# Android studio settings, ctrl+alt+l don't work correct

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, settings

[image]

Hello everyone, need help with android studio settings, project in Kotlin. When i press Ctrl+Alt+L my code get formatted like on first picture. But i need it to be like on second picture. Maybe somebody know how to fix it? Thank.

Comment: that won't be possible buddy. You can have a look at the coding guide here :- https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press `ctr + alt + s -> Editor -> Code Style -> Kotlin` select `Wrapping and Braces` item and set `Do not wrap` for`Function call argument`
[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, you my saver

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl + Shift + Alt + "L" might help